# How to report findings from regression model chosen using stepwise AIC

Tags: regression, model-selection, aic, reporting, stepwise-regression

I want to test the effect of several explanatory variables on an independent. I am using stepwise AIC to chose the best model.

Given that I have found the 'best model' how would you recommend I report the findings (particularly the effect of single variables)?  We are no-longer using p-values, so I presume that talking about statistical significance would be misleading.  Would it be right to say that, supposing $X$ is in the best model, you could report that '$X$ has an important effect on $Y$' and report the delta AIC and effect size? Or would it still be good to report 95% CI?

Comment: How do you expect to “test” something without a p-value? // There are major problems with using stepwise regression for inferential modeling.

Comment: I guess this is at the heart of my question. It has been a while since I have done much regression - and it seems that convention has moved away from using Anova for model selection. 

Would you recommend with Anova to test?

Comment: ANOVA to test what?

Comment: To compare models with and without the variable of interest.

Comment: What have you seen as an alternative?

Comment: As I mention in my question I have seen researchers using stepwise Anova to find the best model (or using model averaging based on AIC) and then reporting those in the model as being important. 

As a alternative to stepwise. Would you recommend creating model based just on expert knowledge?

Comment: One step, baseline model to full model, is fine. Multiple steps start having issues. You seem to be mixing up the selection of covariates (via stepwise selection) and the testing of your variable(s) of interest.